# ASP.NET - Link Button display

Tags: asp.net

I have the following:

```
     <asp:LinkButton ID="View7" runat="server" CommandArgument="View7" CssClass="TopTitle" OnCommand="GotolnkView" Width="108px">Manages Supervisor Manager Information</asp:LinkButton>
```

How do I have it such that it shows like such for the link button:

```
  Manages Supervisor
  Manager Information
```

Note how Manages Supervisor shows at top
and Manager Information shows at bottom

Comment: What have you tried in order to accomplish that?  It's always nice, here, to show what you've attempted, even if it didn't work.  There are several ways to do it, I believe.

Comment: Are you saying that it *should* be like that, and it isn't... or it *shouldn't* be like that, and it is?

Comment: Are those links need to handle different logic? If so, why don't you consider adding different links by using for/foreach loop? Otherwise, if its just a single link, try keeping a <br/> between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this code

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="test" runat="server" text="Manages Supervisor<br/>Manager Information"></asp:LinkButton>
```